# Parsing Dynamic JSON Model in Swift

Tags: json, swift

My app must parse JSON data. The software (IceStats) that generates the data, though, generates JSON with two slightly different structures. Sometimes, the **"source"** value is an array of dictionaries and sometimes it just one dictionary. I can parse the JSON when it is one way or the other, but I don't know how to handle it both ways.

Here is the JSON in the Array version:

```
{
  "icestats": {
    "admin": "dontcontactme@localhost",
    "host": "server.badradio.biz",
    "location": "Airport",
    "server_id": "Icecast 2.4.4",
    "server_start": "Mon, 26 Apr 2021 12:50:47 -0500",
    "server_start_iso8601": "2021-04-26T12:50:47-0500",
    "source": [
      {
        "audio_info": "bitrate=128",
        "bitrate": 128,
        "genre": "Automation",
        "listener_peak": 7,
        "listeners": 0,
        "listenurl": "http://server.badradio.biz:8000/ambient",
        "server_description": "No show is running, tune in for selections from the venerable tape series \"Comfortable & Economical\"",
        "server_name": "Comfortable & Economical",
        "server_type": "audio/mpeg",
        "server_url": "badradio.biz",
        "stream_start": "Fri, 30 Apr 2021 06:51:49 -0500",
        "stream_start_iso8601": "2021-04-30T06:51:49-0500",
        "title": "Vol-15-A",
        "dummy": null
      },
      {
        "listeners": 0,
        "listenurl": "http://server.badradio.biz:8000/stream",
        "dummy": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And here it is in the Dictionary version:

```
{
  "icestats": {
    "admin": "dontcontactme@localhost",
    "host": "server.badradio.biz",
    "location": "Airport",
    "server_id": "Icecast 2.4.4",
    "server_start": "Mon, 26 Apr 2021 12:50:47 -0500",
    "server_start_iso8601": "2021-04-26T12:50:47-0500",
    "source": {
      "audio_info": "bitrate=128",
      "bitrate": 128,
      "genre": "Automation",
      "listener_peak": 2,
      "listeners": 0,
      "listenurl": "http://server.badradio.biz:8000/ambient",
      "server_description": "No show is running, tune in for selections from the venerable tape series \"Comfortable & Economical\"",
      "server_name": "Comfortable & Economical",
      "server_type": "audio/mpeg",
      "server_url": "badradio.biz",
      "stream_start": "Wed, 28 Apr 2021 02:18:31 -0500",
      "stream_start_iso8601": "2021-04-28T02:18:31-0500",
      "title": "Vol-13-A",
      "dummy": null
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, here is my data model that handles the Array version:

```
import Foundation

struct StreamData: Decodable {
    let icestats: IceStats
}

struct IceStats: Decodable {
    let source: [Source]

}

struct Source: Decodable {
    let server_name: String?
    let stream_start: String?
    let title: String?
    let server_description: String?
    let server_url: String?
    let genre: String?
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Ideally, I could just change the format of the JSON, but I am not able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some custom decoding logic to try both cases:

```
struct IceStats: Decodable {
    var source: [Source]
    
    enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
        case source
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let elements = try? container.decode([Source].self, forKey: .source) {
            source = elements
        } else if let element = try? container.decode(Source.self, forKey: .source) {
            source = [element]
        } else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .source, in: container, debugDescription: "Must be either a single or multiple sources!")
        }
    }
}
```

But this can get really long if you also want to decode other properties in `IceStats`, because you'll have to manually write the decoding code for those too. To avoid this, you can use a property wrapper:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct MultipleOrSingle<Element: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let wrappedValue: [Element]
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let elements = try? container.decode([Element].self) {
            wrappedValue = elements
        } else if let element = try? container.decode(Element.self) {
            wrappedValue = [element]
        } else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Container neither contains a single, nor multiple \(Element.self)!")
        }
    }
}

// Now you can just do this!
struct IceStats: Decodable {
    @MultipleOrSingle
    var source: [Source]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your array response your class looks like below and where you get response just decode that response class you will get all data

```
import Foundation

struct Response : Codable {

    let icestats : Icestat?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case icestats = "icestats"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            icestats = Icestat(from: decoder)
    }
}

struct Icestat : Codable {

    let admin : String?
    let host : String?
    let location : String?
    let serverId : String?
    let serverStart : String?
    let serverStartIso8601 : String?
    let source : [Source]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case admin = "admin"
            case host = "host"
            case location = "location"
            case serverId = "server_id"
            case serverStart = "server_start"
            case serverStartIso8601 = "server_start_iso8601"
            case source = "source"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            admin = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .admin)
            host = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .host)
            location = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .location)
            serverId = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .serverId)
            serverStart = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .serverStart)
            serverStartIso8601 = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .serverStartIso8601)
            source = try values.decodeIfPresent([Source].self, forKey: .source)
    }

}

struct Source : Codable {

    let audioInfo : String?
    let bitrate : Int?
    let dummy : AnyObject?
    let genre : String?
    let listenerPeak : Int?
    let listeners : Int?
    let listenurl : String?
    let serverDescription : String?
    let serverName : String?
    let serverType : String?
    let serverUrl : String?
    let streamStart : String?
    let streamStartIso8601 : String?
    let title : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case audioInfo = "audio_info"
            case bitrate = "bitrate"
            case dummy = "dummy"
            case genre = "genre"
            case listenerPeak = "listener_peak"
            case listeners = "listeners"
            case listenurl = "listenurl"
            case serverDescription = "server_description"
            case serverName = "server_name"
            case serverType = "server_type"
            case serverUrl = "server_url"
            case streamStart = "stream_start"
            case streamStartIso8601 = "stream_start_iso8601"
            case title = "title"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            audioInfo = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .audioInfo)
            bitrate = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .bitrate)
            dummy = try values.decodeIfPresent(AnyObject.self, forKey: .dummy)
            genre = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .genre)
            listenerPeak = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .listenerPeak)
            listeners = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .listeners)
            listenurl = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .listenurl)
            serverDescription = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .serverDescription)
            serverName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .serverName)
            serverType = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .serverType)
            serverUrl = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .serverUrl)
            streamStart = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .streamStart)
            streamStartIso8601 = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .streamStartIso8601)
            title = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title)
    }

}
```

decode it like

```
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
print(response.icestats)
```

Comment: This decodes only the array and ignores the dictionary. By the way most of the `init` methods are not needed.

Comment: @vadian thanks for guidance. but, without `init` it will work?

Comment: generally i am using Swifty JSON class and it works great for me.

Comment: *without init it will work?* Yes it will,  the `init` method is being synthesized.